# LWC eslint rule

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, eslint

I am in VSCODE and trying to set eslint rule for LWC using https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc I am unable to set it up properly and lint rules are not firing. Can anybody help me here who implemented this?

Comment: Does Salesforce provide a vscode extension for same ?

Comment: Try asking in the github issues.